# How to fix '*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list' here

Tags: haskell

This is a homework , it's to removing the adjacent duplicates.
The result should like this `removeAdjacentDuplicates [3,1,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,2,2,3] == [3,1,2,4,2,3]`

I knew it's not necessary to use `head` here, but it's not allowed to use rekursion and List-Comprehensions of Form [e | ...]. Only the function in Prelude is permittet, `group` und so on , which in other packages are also not allowed. `map zip filter concat reverse foldr` are recommended.

For example , It's not possible to make this:

```
removeAdjacentDuplicates :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
removeAdjacentDuplicates (x:xs@(y:_))
 | x == y    = x:tail (removeAdjacentDuplicates xs)
 | otherwise = x:removeAdjacentDuplicates xs
```

so I try like this

```
removeAdjacentDuplicates = foldr (\x result -> if ( x == (head result)) then result else (x : result)) []
```

but when I test it, it throw `*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list' here` out

I have tried to add `removeAdjacentDuplicates [] = []` before,
But error is like this

```
Equations for ‘removeAdjacentDuplicates’ have different numbers of arguments
      H7-1.hs:24:1-32
      H7-1.hs:25:1-105
   |
24 | removeAdjacentDuplicates [] = []
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

I don't understand where the problem is, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x == head result` dies if `result` is `[]` -- and `result` is definitely `[]` in the first iteration of `foldr`, so adding a special case for when the input list would not require `foldr` to do any iterations is fixing exactly the wrong case!

Instead of trying to extract a value from the `result` list, you could insert `x` into a list; so consider using the condition

```
[x] == take 1 result
```

instead -- it never dies.

Answer (score 2):

As said by [@DanielWagner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56615479/67579), [**`head :: [a] -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:head) will raise an error for empty lists. We can solve this by using [**`take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take), or by using *pattern matching*:

```
removeAdjacentDuplicates :: (Foldable f, Eq a) => f a -> [a]
removeAdjacentDuplicates = foldr f []
    where f x ys@(y:_) | x == y = ys
          f x ys = (x:ys)
```

here `ys@(y:_)` will match given the list is non-empty, with `y` as head of the list. In that case we thus check if `x == y`, and if that holds, we return `ys`. Otherwise we return `(x:ys)`.